# Update a Pandas MultiIndex DataFrame

Tags: pandas, multi-index

The dataframe "data" has a MultiIndex.

```
data.head()

    Close   High    Low Open    Volume
Symbol  Date                    
A   1999-11-18  28.6358 33.5207 27.3725  
30.6572 59753154
1999-11-19  27.2040 28.9727 26.8253 28.9323  
16172993
1999-11-22  29.3517 29.3517 26.9935 27.8357  
5435127
1999-11-23  27.1198 28.8885 27.1198 28.6358  
5035889
1999-11-24  27.6676 28.2571 26.9513 27.0389  
5141708
```

The dictionary f has a key 'AAPL' which is a regular DataFrame.

```
f['AAPL'].head()

    Open    High    Low Close   Volume
Date                    
2018-06-11  191.350 191.970 190.21  191.23  18308460
2018-06-12  191.385 192.611 191.15  192.28  16911141
2018-06-13  192.420 192.880 190.44  190.70  21638393
2018-06-14  191.550 191.570 190.22  190.80  21610074
2018-06-15  190.030 190.160 188.26  188.84  61719160
```

I'd like to append to data['AAPL'] so that it has the data from f['AAPL']. This works, but is not inplace:

```
data.loc['AAPL'].append(f['AAPL'], verify_integrity=True).tail()

    Close   High    Low Open    Volume
Date                    
2018-07-30  189.91  192.20  189.0700    191.90  21029535
2018-07-31  190.29  192.14  189.3400    190.30  39373038
2018-08-01  201.50  201.76  197.3100    199.13  67935716
2018-08-02  207.39  208.38  200.3500    200.58  62404012
2018-08-03  207.99  208.74  205.4803    207.03  33447396
```

When I try to update data, I get all NaNs.

```
data.loc['AAPL'] = data.loc['AAPL'].append(f['AAPL'], verify_integrity=True).tail()

    Close   High    Low Open    Volume
Date                    
2018-06-04  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2018-06-05  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2018-06-06  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2018-06-07  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2018-06-08  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

**Edit**:
The "data" DataFrame was created with pandas data_reader:

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
data = web.DataReader(['A','AAPL','F'], 'morningstar', start, end)
```

"f" was created the same way, but using 'iex' as the source instead of 'morningstar' (at the moment the morningstar source is returning 404s, so I switched to iex).

Comment: can you add dummy code to create the database ?

Comment: I've updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personal preference: I would first create a temp df with the data to append as a multi index dataframe.

```
toappend = pd.concat([f['AAPL']], keys=['AAPL'], names=['Symbol'])
```

And then create a new dataframe by appending the data and new data.

```
newdata = data.append(toappend, verify_integrity=True)
```

or if you prefer to do it in one line:

```
newdata = data.append(pd.concat([f['AAPL']], keys=['AAPL'], names=['Symbol']), verify_integrity=True)
```

My full test code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

symbols = ['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC']
dates = ['2018-06-11', '2018-06-12', '2018-06-13']
cols = ['Close', 'High', 'Low']

midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([symbols, dates], names=['Symbol', 'Date'])
data= pd.DataFrame(10, midx, cols)

aapldf = pd.DataFrame(15, dates, cols)
aapldf.index.name = 'Date'
f = {'AAPL': aapldf}

toappend = pd.concat([f['AAPL']], keys=['AAPL'], names=['Symbol'])

newdata = data.append(toappend, verify_integrity=True)
print(newdata)
```

Answer (score 1):

I still don't know why assigning to data.loc['AAPL'] doesn't work, but the following does:

```
# Converts dict with keys as tickers, DataFrame as values, to a DataFrame with a MultiIndex
new_data = pd.concat(f)

# Just append, and sort index to align the dates
data = data.append(new_data).sort_index()
```